# How to hide columns which has all values less than a number in excel sheet?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am newbie to the excel formulas.I have an excel sheet which has lets say 100 rows and 100 columns. columns have different values from 0 to 20. I want to hide the columns if all values of the column is less than a given number. Or in different way I want to display only those columns which any value is greater than a given number.

Comment: Is VBA an option?

Comment: no . only excel

Comment: VBA (Visual Basic for Applications) is part of excel. It allows you to have code behind the scenes in Excel

Comment: But I dont know VBA

Comment: Unfortunately I wouldn't know how to do this without VBA. If there is a way, I'm sure someone will help you. Good luck

Comment: you can provide the VBA solution here, It might help if somebody knows VBA. I will also refer your answer if I dont find anything within excel.

Comment: You can’t do this with formulas, you need to use VBA.

Comment: I know C# , not VBA. Let me know if can be done in C#

Comment: Is there any way to get the column names which has the greater value then the number using the excel formula?

Comment: No need for formulas or VBA. Just use a filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Throw the below code into a new module within your workbook.  If you're not sure how to do that, then Google "*How do I create a new module in my Excel VBA project*" ...

```
Public Sub HideColumnsBasedOnCriteria()
    Dim rngCells As Range, lngCol As Long, lngRow As Long, lngThreshold As Long
    Dim bBelowThreshold As Boolean

    Set rngCells = Selection

    lngThreshold = InputBox("Enter a threshold amount ...", "Threshold Amount", 10)

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With rngCells
        For lngCol = 1 To .Columns.Count
            bBelowThreshold = True

            For lngRow = 1 To .Rows.Count
                If .Cells(lngRow, lngCol) >= lngThreshold Then
                    bBelowThreshold = False
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next

            If .Columns(lngCol).Hidden <> bBelowThreshold Then
                .Columns(lngCol).Hidden = bBelowThreshold
            End If
        Next
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

... then select your cells (not the columns, but the range of data like shown below) and then run the macro.

[image]

If you don't know how to run the macro then Google "*How do I execute a macro in Excel*".  If you don't have the developer tab, Google "*How do I make the developer tab visible in Excel*".

The columns with the number less than what you provide will then be hidden.

This is without error checking and the like but it will get you going.  If you need to take the threshold amount from a cell on the worksheet, that is an easy addition.

I hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking is impossible: the result of an Excel-formula is a number of a piece of text, not the command for hiding a cell or a range of cells.

There is one interesting this, and that's conditional formatting: it does not allow you to hide an entire column, but it can, as mentioned by the name, modify the formatting of your cell, based on some condition. As a formatting, you might choose the background colour of your cells.

The difficult part here seems: how will you check if the values of an entire column are smaller than one value? This can be checked using a simple idea: every value is smaller than one particular value if the maximum of those values is smaller than that particular value, and here you have your conditional formatting, based on a formula: just base it on the formula `=MAX(F1:F100)<=5`, apply this conditional formatting on every cell of column `F` and apply a background colour accordingly.